# Unsubscribe blurb arbitrarily being removed

Tags: php, mailgun

I am using PHP and Mailgun via a CRON job that sends emails to subscribed email addresses, scheduled to run daily though there may not be an email queued every day.

The issue that I am having is that during test runs it seems as though an unsubscribe blurb that I have is arbitrarily being removed prior to the email being sent.

Here is the code that I'm using to add my unsubscribe blurb:

```
$email = array(
  'subject' => $row['subject'],
  'body'    => $row['body'] . "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n" . "No longer wish to receive emails from us? You may unsubscribe below. Beware, in unsubscribing, you will miss out on any information we share via email going forward."
);
```

It is worth mentioning that the `$row['subject']` is a String with HTML markup.

Here is the code that I'm using to A) perform a mail merge prior to sending the email and B) actually send the email.

```
function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $body) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:removed for privacy');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/removed for privacy/messages');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'from' => $from,
        'to' => $to,
        'subject' => $subject,
        'html' => $body
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

function mail_merge($text, $agency, $sender, $receiver, $efs) {
  // Replace any mail merger fields from the body
  $text = str_replace('[agency.name]',        $agency['name'],              $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.address]',     $agency['address_formatted'], $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.phone]',       $agency['phone'],             $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.fax]',         $agency['fax'],               $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.email]',       $agency['email'],             $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.signature]',   $agency['signature'],         $text);
  $text = str_replace('[agency.referral]',    $agency['referral'],          $text);
  $text = str_replace('[sender.firstname]',   $sender['first_name'],        $text);
  $text = str_replace('[sender.lastname]',    $sender['last_name'],         $text);
  $text = str_replace('[sender.email]',       $sender['email'],             $text);
  $text = str_replace('[sender.signature]',   $sender['signature'],         $text);
  $text = str_replace('[receiver.firstname]', $receiver['first_name'],      $text);
  $text = str_replace('[receiver.lastname]',  $receiver['last_name'],       $text);
  $text = str_replace('[receiver.email]',     $receiver['email'],           $text);
  $text = str_replace('[receiver.phone]',     $receiver['phone'],           $text);
  $text = str_replace('[efs.firstname]',      $efs['first_name'],           $text);
  $text = str_replace('[efs.lastname]',       $efs['last_name'],            $text);
  $text = str_replace('[efs.email]',          $efs['email'],                $text);
  $text = str_replace('[efs.phone]',          $efs['phone'],                $text);

  return $text;
}
```

As I mentioned, I have situations where *some* of the test emails that are being sent out do not include the appended new lines and optout blurb. Is this something that could be caused when the cURL request is executed to send the email via Mailgun's API or is it something that I'm inadvertently doing in my code and just not catching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was never able to figure out why the blurb was arbitrarily being removed, I was able to have my problem resolved by customizing the unsubscribe template from my domain's control panel in MailGun:

```
Domains > [Domain Name] > Tracking Settings > Customize unsubscribe templates
```